# Inverse of piecewise bijective function

Tags: polynomials, inverse

Given

$$f(x) = -2 x ^ 3 + 3 x ^ 2, 0 <= x <= 1$$

where I'd like to find $f^{-1}(x)$ defined on the same domain.

I've tried using Mathematica where I get an answer, but it's not defined exactly in the interval I care about. I'd also be happy with an approximation or any tips.

Comment: Is this really the problem you want to solve? Or is it a step to solve another problem?

Comment: I'm trying to have an inverse function for each-in-out functions that are common in animation.

Comment: Mathematica gives a list of three solutions, and the third solution (the one where $1-i\sqrt3$ appears in a numerator) is actually the function that you want. I agree that it would be nicer to have a form not involving complex numbers.

Comment: @GregMartin I'm only getting one answer on WolframAlpha.

Comment: The solution in question is $$f^{-1}(y) = \frac{1}{4} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{2 \sqrt{y^2-y}+2 y-1}+\frac{1-i
   \sqrt{3}}{4 \sqrt[3]{2 \sqrt{y^2-y}+2 y-1}}+\frac{1}{2}.$$